# Does the language filter show all languages by default?

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

I'm looking at a Drupal 6 site with the following modules installed, all of which I think are contributing to translation:

- Internationalization
- Locale
- Content Translation

As I am not experienced with site translation I'm not sure which module is contributing to this, but the "Language Switcher" block shows both English and French for all content, regardless of the language choice assigned in the node, or if there are any translations present.

It is claimed that previously, if there was only an English translation for the node, then only English would be available from the language switcher block. However, if I add a new node, with just an English translation, I can still select French, which, because there is no translated node, takes the user to the internal node path, e.g. instead of:

`/en/mycontent/foo`

it would be

`/fr/node/232`

which of course, breaks contexts and what-not.

So what module does the language switcher block get provided by in this case and should it always show both languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Switch Language" block created by "Locale" module which is the most fundamental  language handler in drupal. Its purpose it to switch user interface between languages. If translation exists for certain node it will used if not, only interface changes.

"Content Translation" module handles relations and links between translated nodes. The link you need is something like the language link/s that, by default, displayed inside node's links area.

I am not aware of existing  module that display these node links in block.
But you can display this list using code.

First, get can get an array needed links using [translation_link()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!translation!translation.module/function/translation_link/6) that supplied by "Content Translation" module

```
$node_translations = translation_link('node', $node_object);
```

Than, create HTML list out of that array, using theme_links(),

```
print theme('links', $node_translations, $attributes = array('class' => 'links langs more-classes-if-you-wish'));
```

To display this in block you can create new custom block with php input format or create template file for that block and make your code live there.
To get node object in block you can use

```
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
   $node_object = node_load(arg(1));
  }
```